# error in embedding deep zoom

Tags: silverlight, deepzoom

I created a website separately first and then opened it in Expression web to insert the deep zoom image in, but I keep getting this error:

```
"Add the page to a site and then try to insert the deep zoom image"
```

I have no idea what to do next, could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you inserting the image? Deep zoom image is not a single image. It is collection of images. One embeds the deep zoom player that comes with deep zoom composer into a web page to display those images. Did you use deep zoom composer for creating deep zoom images? You can try http://www.imagesurf.net which allows online automated deep zoom/open zoom of photos and also allows to embed it in your web page. I am affiliated with the site.